# Android Can't Add Another Card List

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-listview, android-fragments

I want to create 'card' list like http://ryanharter.com/blog/2013/01/31/how-to-make-an-android-card-list/ . I was using https://github.com/justmyfreak/android-slidingmenu to create sliding menu.

I want to place card list inside my `res/layout/fragment_home.xml`. I created `bg_card.xml` inside `res/drawable/bg_card.xml` with code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"
               android:dither="true">

        <corners android:radius="2dp"/>

        <solid android:color="#ccc"/>

    </shape>
</item>

<item android:bottom="2dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"
           android:dither="true">

        <corners android:radius="2dp"/>

        <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>

        <padding android:bottom="8dp"
                 android:left="8dp"
                 android:right="8dp"
                 android:top="8dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

Inside my `fragment_home.xml` I wrote :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight">
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_card">

    <!-- Card Contents go here -->

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="My Text View"
            android:id="@+id/textView"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

It is working and showing :

[image]

I Tried to add 2nd card list by adding `LinearLayout` inside my `FrameLayout` of `fragment_home.xml` but 2nd card list was not displayed. 
Is there something I missed or wrong?

Thank you

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. *I managed to add 2nd card list* - you're trying to add a `ListView` inside `fragment_home.xml`?

Comment: I want to add 2nd and another card list, but it is not displayed.